# How to filter object in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my question, in the first picture. 
I map my object, it correctly displays my objects, 
I would like to filter only the items that contain the name beers.

```
    let addedItems = this.props.items.length ?
    (      
        this.props.items.map(item => {
        return (
            <div className="homeProduct">
                    <Media  >
                        <Media body className="mediaBodyContainerHome">
                            <div className="mediaBodyTitle">
                                <Media heading className='MediaTextHome'>
                                    {item.title}
                                </Media>
                            </div>

                        </Media>
                    </Media>
```

I show you my table

```
     const initState = {

items: [
    {id:1,title: "Hype PA (Demi-Pinte)",  ctg: "beers", },
    {id:2,title:'Fuso jaune - kombucha',  ctg: "cocktail",},
    {id:3,title:'Tartinades Terre d\'Apéro', ctg: "planches",},  
],

addedItems:[],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
let addedItems = this.props.items.length ?
    (      
        this.props.items.filter(item => item.ctg==="beers").map(item => {
        return (
            <div className="homeProduct">
                    <Media  >
                        <Media body className="mediaBodyContainerHome">
                            <div className="mediaBodyTitle">
                                <Media heading className='MediaTextHome'>
                                    {item.title}
                                </Media>
                            </div>

                        </Media>
                    </Media>
            <div>
    ) : "Another rest condition"
```

Comment: Great. Make sure mark the answer right if this solves your problem so that it can be helpful for others as well.